# Записи в записях wordpress

Tags: wordpress

На сайте http://mangaclub.ru/ на главной странице выводятся записи. При переходе на страницу записи чуть ниже есть список залитых глав. Как реализовать это на wordpress, чтобы была возможность добавлять записи в записи?

Answer (score 0):

> Как реализовать это на wordpress, чтобы была возможность добавлять записи в записи?

Это не "записи в записи", а "связанные записи".

По дефолту можно разбить пост тегом `<-- nextpage -->` и вывести пагинацию. Но это не оч хороший вариант. И пост огромный и предстоит решать проблемы с корректной индексацией.

Можно произвольным полями связать, но это ИМХО не оч удобно при добавлении новых глав.

Есть готовые плагины для [по-главного](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=chapter%20post) (от слова "глава") вывода контента. Вот сходу нашлось https://wordpress.org/plugins/mpl-publisher/, https://wordpress.org/plugins/organize-series/

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - записи и рубрики. При этом главы, например [глава 01](http://mangaclub.ru/manga/view/691-alice-in-borderland/v-c01.html#01) - это записи. Все главы одной манги находятся в рубрике `Alice in Borderland`. [Информация о манге](http://mangaclub.ru/691-alice-in-borderland.html) - это страница рубрики `Alice in Borderland`. Текст в верхней части страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно поместить в описание рубрики `Alice in Borderland`.

Возможны еще 150 иных способов, но этот представляется самым простым.